# WCF: Why WebSecurity.CurrentUserId is -1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, simplemembership

I am sort of new with creating web service using WCF. I just have a quick question. I am validating the user using SimpleMembershipProvider. In some calls to my web service, I need to retrieve the current userid. So, I am using `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` which I used in MVC.NET.

To explain better, here is my web.config and as you can see, I am using custom validator:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="behaviorCfg">
                ...
                ...
                ...
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WarehouseWebService.WarehouseValidator, WarehouseWebService" />
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<system.serviceModel>
```

Here is my custom validator (WarehouseValidator.cs):

```
public class WarehouseValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("warehouseConnStr", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", false);

        if (!WebSecurity.Login(userName, password, true))
            throw new FaultException("Invalid username or password.");
    }
}
```

Now, in some calls (functions) on the webservice, I need to get the CurrentUserId and I am using `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId`, but it returns -1.

All other property also seems not being initialized. For example, `WebSecurity.CurrentUserName` is empty and `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` is false.

This is weird because `WebSecurity.Login(userName, password, true)` is successful and I am using the same method in my website (MVC.NET) and it worked fine.

I know it is something to do with the cookies, I even tried to do:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
```

But nothing has worked so far!

Any idea why?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);` you need to set `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` to `true` in your config file, it stating that your services will participate in the ASP.NET pipeline; so items like ASP.NET cookies are available.

so try by adding

```
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: I actually have it on my web.config (I've updated my question). Is it a right place to put it?